# Video Upload to Amazon S3 in Swift

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have tried video file upload to Amazon S3 in Swift but I failed. Here is my code. I hope you can guide me.

```
@IBAction func uploadVideoBtnClicked(sender: AnyObject)
{
    //-- Add Amazon Video upload code

    var uploadRequest: AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()

    uploadRequest.bucket = "appFile"
    uploadRequest.key = "foldername/test.mov"

    //Move video file to the application folder so it can be read

    var savedVideoURLToBeUsed =  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ThisIsTheVideoIWantToUse") as! String
    print("Video saved in Store: \(savedVideoURLToBeUsed)")

    var url: NSURL = self.videoPath

    uploadRequest.body = url

    print("URL: \(url)")

    let transferManager: AWSS3TransferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager()
    transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: { (AWSTask) -> AnyObject! in

        //Handle errors
        if AWSTask.error != nil {

            println("Error in uploading the video: \(AWSTask.error)")

            // Retrive information important for later downloading
        } else {
            println("Video upload successful..")
            var uploadResult: AnyObject! = AWSTask.result
            println("Upload result: \(uploadResult)")


        }
        return nil

    })

}
```

and I have added pod library file on existing project.

Answer (score 1):

**Pass the URL Of video in uploadVideo**

```
func uploadVideo(fileUrl : URL){

  let newKey = "video/1.mov"

  let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
  uploadRequest?.body = fileUrl as URL
  uploadRequest?.key = newKey
  uploadRequest?.bucket = "YourBucketName"
  uploadRequest?.acl = AWSS3ObjectCannedACL.publicRead 
  uploadRequest?.contentType = "movie/mov"

  uploadRequest?.uploadProgress = { (bytesSent, totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend) -> Void in
      DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
          let amountUploaded = totalBytesSent // To show the updating data status in label.
          print(amountUploaded)
      })
  }

  let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()
  transferManager.upload(uploadRequest!).continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.mainThread(), block: { (task) in
      if task.error != nil {
          print(task.error.debugDescription)
      } else {
          // Do something with your result.
          print("done")
      }
      return nil
  })

}
```