# Upload video to Amazon S3 from Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload a video on Amazon S3 using Swift but I can not find any online help.
Can someone help me?

Thank you!

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/mobile-hub-add-aws-mobile-user-data-storage.html

Comment: I guess you have to see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34770099/video-upload-to-amazon-s3-in-swift also you can check this : https://aws.amazon.com/tr/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/mobile-sdk-ios-swift/

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!
use_frameworks!

target 'AmazonS3Upload' do
pod 'AWSS3'
end
```

2. Run the next command from Terminal:

   pod install
3. Open the generated workspace. And after that we can implement uploading of files using frameworks from Pods.
4. We need to import 2 modules:

import AWSS3

import AWSCore

5. Set up a AWS configuration using your credentials. For example:

   let accessKey = "..."
   let secretKey = "..."

   let credentialsProvider = AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(accessKey: accessKey, secretKey: secretKey)

   let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.usEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)

   AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
6. Create an upload request:

   let url = ...URL to your file...
   let remoteName = "Name of uploaded file"
   let S3BucketName = "Name of your bucket on Amazon S3"

   let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()!
   uploadRequest.body = url
   uploadRequest.key = remoteName
   uploadRequest.bucket = S3BucketName
   uploadRequest.contentType = "image/jpeg"
   uploadRequest.acl = .publicRead
7. And upload using AWSS3TransferManager.

   let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()
   transferManager?.upload(uploadRequest).continue({ (task: AWSTask) -> Any? in
     if let error = task.error {
       print("Upload failed with error: ((error.localizedDescription))")
     }

   if let exception = task.exception {
       print("Upload failed with exception ((exception))")
     }

   if task.result != nil {
       let url = AWSS3.default().configuration.endpoint.url
       let publicURL = url?.appendingPathComponent(uploadRequest.bucket!).appendingPathComponent(uploadRequest.key!)

   ```
   print("Uploaded to:\(publicURL)")
   ```

   }

   return nil
   })

Comment: sorry: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0):

You can also follow https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/storage to use Amplify CLI to provision S3 and Amplify framework's Storage plugin to interact with S3.